# Applying different labeling options at different scales to different points (that aren't easily separated from the other points)

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, labeling, maplex

I am creating maps (in ArcMap 10.1) for a web-based application.  There are more than 500 places to be labeled at some scale (the map scales range from 1:32 million to 1:1.5 million).  As you can imagine, some of the places are very near one another and some are far away from other places.

I would like those places that are farther away from other places (where there is no labeling conflict) to be labeled when the map is at a smaller scale than those for which zooming in to a larger scale is needed to avoid a cloud of overlapping names. (I don't mind them overlapping at the largest scales...)

I am using the Maplex labeling but don't see how to easily accomplish this. At some point they may still overlap, so I cannot use the "never overlap" option.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest following [ESRI's map authoring considerations](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Map_authoring_considerations/0154000003zp000000/) and setting up several copies of your layer (using definition queries). Apply different scale ranges to them, especially if your data source contains as many places as you mentioned.

You can [create label classes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Using_label_classes_to_label_features_from_the_same_layer_differently/00s80000000v000000/) and [set scale ranges](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Setting_scale_ranges_for_label_classes/00s800000023000000/) per class, but keep in mind that using the Maplex labelling engine for a map service is [generally not a good idea](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000003m0000000). Unfortunately it will probably take a while to set the labelling up correctly, particularly because your map will be web-based. People will quickly navigate away from your app if they are distracted by something like too many labels in one spot.